# regex matching pattern in java

Tags: java, regex

I am struggling to understand a simple `regex`. I googled around. somehow it is not striking me.

Here is the method:

```
public static void testMethod(){
        String line = "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?";
        String pattern = "(.*)(\\d+)(.*)";

        // Create a Pattern object
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        // Now create matcher object.
        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
        if (m.find( )) {
           System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
           System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
           System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
           System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(3) );
        }
    }
```

Here is the output:

I was expecting `group(2)` to print `3000`. but why it prints only `0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Group 2 captured text only contains `0` because of the first greedy `.*`. It matched up to the last digit, and let `\d+` have only the last digit. See [demo of your regex](https://regex101.com/r/kF6zG1/1).

To fix it, use lazy dot matching:

```
(.*?)(\d+)(.*)
   ^
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/kF6zG1/2)

Comment: See [*Watch Out for The Greediness!*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) and [*The Greedy Trap*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) for a comprehensive description of how backtracking works with greedy and lazy quantifiers. I just tried to shortly explain the root of the problem, and 1 possible way of fixing it. Surely, depending on what you need, you might use  a negated character class (e.g. `[^0-9]*`), or tempered greedy token.

Answer (score 2):

You need `([^0-9.]*)(\\d+)(.*)`.

The first group matching everything until last zero as you have `+` in second group. You need to escape numbers from the first group.